# FTP connection using just the IP or IP and port number

Tags: windows, ftp

I am trying to edit some files on my windows server using Direct FTP. If I connect to the server using just the IP address everything is fine, and the file can be edited and saved remotely on the server.
If I connect to the server using IP and some other port number ie: 22.224.123.114:1313 (router would redirect to port 21) the only thing I can do is just navigate through the server folders and open the files for editing(Direct FTP coffeecup). Any changes cannot be saved, I receive error such as the host cannot be found. 
I prefer to go with the second choice but I have no idea how to fix the error. Any idea would be great.

Comment: Are you connecting in passive mode when you get your problem?

Comment: No, not pasive. I've tried but the result is the same....error

Comment: The one thing I don't get from your description is the fact that some connections go through a router and others don't.  Clarifying that will probably make your problem stand out.

Comment: Everything is going through the router. Using the port number is just an extra-caution to mask the opening port 21, and I prefer that way my opening port being masked. But if I mask the port number I cannot edit the files, just to see them. Makes sense?

Comment: Nope.  :)   Do you mean that it works fine when you forward requests coming into port 21 of your router and not when the requests come to port 1313?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: If there are no other variables, then the error must come from your router's port forwarding rules.

Comment: Just to be sure, verify that both ports are sent to your FTP server on port 21.

Comment: There is nothing extra. You think is from my router? Not proper forwarding the rule? It can be....but how come I am able to connect and navigate through server folders and see all the files? I am able to open any file on my local editor but when I am done editing, save and.........error -> IP:1313 host not found.......close the file not being saved and browse again through server folders?

Comment: I'm not sure why but the server should be receiving both requests at port 21 on its side, which would prevent it from even knowing there's a difference.  That obviously depends if you did validate that both go to port 21 of the FTP server.  If that's not the case, the problem could be the FTP server's firewall.

Comment: So I have to validate the port 1313 on the server machine firewall?

Comment: I still don't get why you need the local machine to listen on two different ports.  The outside user only sees the router.  The router should direct traffic coming from the outside to port 1313 towards the local server's port 21.  That's it!

Comment: Not sure who you think you'd be fooling other than yourself by forwarding the incoming traffic to a different port number.

Comment: I just read is somehow useful if you use different port instead a real one. For example remote desktop 3389 using as 1313 -> 3389. Just thinking.

Comment: The only port people on the Internet will see is the one configured with a port forward in your router.  Using a non standard port for that does slightly reduce attacks, but changing the port of the local server has no impact at all.